# Can't run python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

Hello~ I have installed django-bootstrap-ui-2.0.0 and django-admin startproject, and tried both python and python3 manage.py runserver. However, it says that no such file or directory. Am I missing some functions that have to pip install? Much thanks!

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\
Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\Pyshop\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory  
PS C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Pyshop>
```

Comment: Well, does `C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Pyshop\manage.py` exist? Please read [ask].

Comment: Whoever upvoted this needs to read [Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/354577)

Comment: Make sure you're running the command from the directory which contains manage.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because you haven't activated the virtual environment. The basic reason is that the system is not able to find manage.py on that location.

Comment: If we were seeing something like "cannot import Django", yes, maybe. But the presence or absence of `manage.py` has nothing to do with the virtual environment. It's just a file on the filesystem.

Comment: Since you don't really provide an answer, please leave just a comment till you gather more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:
cd mysite
python manage.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you're on windows pycharm can create the virtual env for you. if that's the case try running

```
venv\Scripts\activate
```

if it says that the script is disabled on this system then just run powershell as administrator and run this command:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

then just input Accept all and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but its just because the 'manage.py' file was not in the right folder. Try to find where the 'manage.py' file is.

(venv) PS C:\Users\Desktop\trabalho\python_all\projetao> python manage.py runserver

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\Desktop\trabalho\python_all\projetao\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

My 'manage.py' file was in "python_all\projetao\site" so i had to write = cd site
then it showed
PS C:\Users\Desktop\trabalho\python_all\site>

Then python manage.py runserver worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

find the right location of manage.py and navigate path using cd, then run..python.exe manage.py runserver